# 2 dimensional array doesn't work properly in python

Tags: python

So i was trying to recreate game of life in python using a 2 dimensional array, but i stumbled into a really weird bug.
To make the array i made this function:

```
def MakeGrid(height):
    gridY = []
    grid = []
    for i in range(height):
        gridY.append(False)
    for i in range(height):
        grid.append(gridY)
    return(grid)
```

But there is a really weird bug where if i try to change a False into a True in only 1 spot, it changes everywhere diagonally.
Here's an example:

```
grid = MakeGrid(2) # grid is now [[False,False], [False,False]]
grid[0][0] = True #grid should be [[True, False], [False, False]], but it's actually [[True, False], [True, False]]
```

I really don't know what causes this but it's really annoying me and i would really love some help.

Comment: try `grid.append(gridY.copy())` and read https://www.python-course.eu/python3_deep_copy.php

Comment: Both lists point to the same object in memory since you appended `gridY` `height` number of times. Hence changing one element in `gridY` changes that element for all lists pointing to `gridY`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, but rather the intended behavior when appending the exact same list over and over again. Since the you're appending the same list (`gridY`) into `grid`, they all share the same **memory** inside of `grid`; meaning that a change in one element (or more) in any of the lists inside of `grid` will apply to all other lists inside of `grid` since they're the **same object**.

Look at the following:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = []
y.append(x)
y.append(x)
y[0] == x  # True (same list contents)
y[0] is x  # Also True! (same memory, exact same list)
```

Thus you would need to append a copy of that list, that doesn't share the same memory/identity, but the same contents using `.copy()`

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is `grid` array is storing many pointers to the same `gridY` part in the memory. When you change one pointer, the whole `gridY` changes. So when you change one `False` in `gridY` to `True`, the whole `gridY` changes.
You could use

```py
def MakeGrid(height):
    gridY = []
    grid = []
    for i in range(height):
        gridY.append(False)
    for i in range(height):
        grid.append(gridY[:])
    return(grid)
```

or

```py
def MakeGrid(height):
    gridY = []
    grid = []
    for i in range(height):
        gridY.append(False)
    for i in range(height):
        grid.append(gridY.copy())
    return(grid)
```

as @Epsi95 mentioned

Answer (score 0):

It is an aliasing problem.
A list is an Object in python, and here you have decelerated `gridY` as a list object and are constantly changing it. By appending it constantly to `grid` you are not creating new objects of different length but are adding the same object multiple times. When you try to change in once, you are changing it throughout `grid`